# Using AudioTrack to play base64 encoded audio String (converted to byte array) just produces white noise

Tags: android, audio, audiotrack

I am trying to playback base64 encoded .wav audio data on Android, via AudioTrack, and all I'm getting is a very short burst of white noise.

I presume it's in .wav format anyway - it was recorded via JavaScript using my Mac's built-in microphone and converted to base64.

I've possibly set the variables wrong when creating the AudioTrack (bit of guesswork involved there) - I've guessed at the sample rate and encoding, and put the buffer size as that of the entire chunk of data. Very grateful for any assistance.

```
playChannelAudio("data:application/octet-stream;base64,GkXfo59ChoEBQveBAULygQRC84EIQoKEd2VibUKHgQRChYECGFOAZwH/////////FUmpZpkq17GDD0JATYCGQ2hyb21lV0GGQ2hyb21lFlSua7+uvdeBAXPFh+lZ/IvV7yqDgQKGhkFfT1BVU2Oik09wdXNIZWFkAQEAAIC7AAAAAADhjbWERzuAAJ+BAWJkgSAfQ7Z1Af/////////ngQCjQZSBAACA+4O1bX7U7Fau4djaow6/qEcFOx2D6vgdTWqanSWTXXa4MzJRsP2c4GEeQwl5/cRiYFl3QmBVeh8n5mGhkgidhLFrDoCIMEJBptK5vggcJl5zwHJSDWDOFwrI/RRvrygpr+L+fHCQ8vnKQfn6W+U1MYhPc4u/xVkm4pp1qsZTyEXM3SQLnlOPNR5Lrp0q7lSyiezMrJ9JpcC3GBB4PrxIhyN09K7iyACAS3gPH1J3dmCt1JDNkJ/hpZRRU2mEPBC/ooXsqZ24Znqkr4XqmHfybYX0tEu5iTz7gngLbxiyPPEfcKYKpwAljaLLjOINVSna8jmkulRVNOIJ1edk2pGnwP5+FhU/5mia2w3sniEBjvBS5W2WiXOU40qYCG+0LY7+WmFFAovpUddWzC1Jv5T6HpmLELnSYojoC6QKC8ECn8m7y0L9EIoMGkDH04Fk6l359StgSGpqqp1BVhCiMHzebvOM4pRXDzLJdCsYi3WFQfWf+ojKKZixVh3iuDDaKJqhxio5xBmXH/SDTlwQedAL06NBeIEAPID7g3J/UCJbxeOHYWvJS3wNcvuxbIec2FaOSbdQcvHzwSskKKkvECoM9Jfm1LAAQx0DP55dIkNIPZlJ73xEkG5O+kNF7RZsgYsyn5OtSXHXhefGCDWqsmmzwnsA0ZbhxDimpnpADKg2rzWtb86QnGmqOWJ0zZOFhaHIQSzLI0kgw9njqgL9OT7vmvVhAxzLxLkaXyL4MgxAU4vN/+ZVXYA4j9PlOnW2/KFxIeCtfyVZdXrT3wEv7KV1SePn53y9+6DfN/nWjLQLKyGBZcFzQs0jmmlPOSozjX6Y8yDFsMKKD1jRoR60u8TxRg0VpbnPrvu9tS2CNkkG+ZrCZ6RYFORlTPvf2fgyomntOm9TIVxJ2q3VUSxAKhvscppe/8ZliUX+SGHz9sCDfWvtc3zODhnIIZU/NhEvEnKlcFLzWyxR7PI5gZrjlRl1W7Yzwg0XE9/e9cteLDJOh26+LxudE8f3JE9U6iqMzdKUBgaLMw983olKovOjQYOBAHeA+wMBPFo7uHMVOYLUJY6PbuHbf15Kof+rK4W2a8ImQZwuvCJRtPm96WykA1jiQ0ZhHiVdgoiyRWj1VGYbzLHCO0gBiirHCnO8NKGmPC0N26enV87BCklvBxFdYtdWrtf3Hw5JutpxIjH/X9zCxzCBc7/teyrGgVBzsRIgfeQRNMUAIdoCDVYHjUbuJV8L/4l4X2GI9k8/YPMrZSRi5N4t/ErQHSRvATvZwlpu0IkNZwvbgVrnqTqCJx5YU3mvaX3TGeNdYV95+vURcGS9Fy65lwcMRlgR2D2NVDwIizeJlOAtd5ytIXUqqOCAsvQ/VyaCpYffWAODum6sYGxfMSgFAhC8vje12DXABaCLPtP9SLl2IMskQzzu27fjSEpB88rLz7z+pasELVJiS549m4vVDzC82uuPA/suROwilik401ZviCUq2TcAa9AyoxULW3nQ6Pp50qYNYzNbon4GCHZs6NNJ1k+cT/o7nLvUUFXSsMzyO3KtM9avJI05Gu6j8lGjQYiBALOA+4N/jKzYtnzc9/RwpuDTPT0qUNnKk/oVeuhiQhO+FCHRqeORKY3un0biJnBA8F81VICXeF5tM4zdWUYNhmzuDcHyzAPKdvDHf+rbTtgkHaQ+gsxEdCeP6IAvkUL4yQ4fFsHTYQMQMZN7NtU7y7xrhWcGFKvPKgucWYvFXmfVt+hZoJsDe8rLNDpTgGkWROrM/f2d2BBzGxOr3DwgRtfWea/4eBaHtVQyyTtgEWzAmlf62mJBhIB+CDdpbK7cSnmOpv44voTUiLheEsipyiZDYK/p36IdeTjI+KyFUPHM8/qnxYM4/nt+RWXG5/C2gKI5NxGP7utnD5ZjeLyt86Vud1QwEvUMYLpYBBcNcTPuq0T9/0l9Mf0aUUgBbdBvbVBqdAnX5hNFbE84e+MAlhaNKEBm9f8XmT/rhYinbMi550hFe7yLjXHv9fA9GCpt5rFBVM2uNGWdYBs4AAaqpf5IoLWDLsmvpvmI19lfi6V9Xmg+nMy0jBVmkbuHKRa3yWMfOIEn7KNB4YEA8ID7g32rELy1GQKuxIl5B/aM/AfmF6TNbWgP2pOmtQMwP66/6jFYHdQEeySjCv7q2gSJd6e/nc+5sn1n6An94m1eIRfZoF76yIMKQ0DJwSYhND0+DQXsL214QxkPPI6+XhlRva8tXp0H8ID04GqzRvOPUkeXvSIuqScy9bfwGO3beyl7M/g3mcB4BMVex0yOZOKosheOtGcpEw3uj8/+nqMwEn2XAK383mWzCDMiS6QOhwFbCXazBELLDBhrl8W5VzAivleW9pEmqkZ4EpicBpfw502AoIjV27wl94hUYajZVbC2yxwBaY0ZX1dhnFExWh3FFyTXWpluClzFf3As9Uos58aDaeYkCwpHPZ1/ebf5AZhQxYo9EmsucnVOiCyOeYHF+HHFLC4pIgczboB8vbiu+ZJNiowuzmXcAQcjkyxdcZqoUS1fcmzm4f2vQyFt6v0zBYCnMyz2hkc32ZX1v+8H3hfLgNhKqdEddkIBAl0z7eQ2SY+iEkbGDDANd7TxPuPETi+w/0A8W4G9DRKrcZ1Zg/W6qmDMvWoVXQ46j7XNZgc+GM0py45MhIC5BPRUCTzch/rcoeI3V1QNLM5VT75aOVwbYpAoWMpzKkTCLnJb6HfZa4SyD18YzEJbuVejQamBASyA+4Oeg9tpEF2nbLtZ1wmMOnfPgMMT7IaNOVG9Uc0sDCVHIvTScsX4NbFveXogXpUe6N16y/286kziOGrIWCYJ5aepjXfGEVQ+RzlpVYGTAsZkT6IdJBWBUxBY6If4EKU+O1imJeLAzZaiK0SNudQPEZYk36XTmeVRPYTCMSlhX7kaCFXO5MD4YE7S+W5sGPWkutNW+RplOZb66uv9lARKzkpJOdKQl0Si9+IabNfPYA6WXXm+vJgjA5kHpLEhYex3mYP3LK31EJq+7E9GlXfhpGIOJG9vciNZo/O+z3RK7F4bHg0OWe0BP8DT8d8ONRyqrMnk2J8cqQZv4K2r8gYblOKUurML0ahyT9hFjgdtl7DfsmqYT4C19Tre0a3UxZXeuPydY1F9GacfVX7iZJPNz81qR6LHu2JbAnFp47IwEqcfZu0mwT9o3tmAShsIaOqF+yj1uBtBjL1ISB4Gl5WQlC0id6gxM1r7wsFsqmZ8hFcLBM3jSaIF47T99jBeCyhNUGmvJvpCV0krMmRxeSmT1PXRBM/7+HIafjuOo84FYtxZ5pl/e6NBhoEBaID7g3+ASqVxcwJV8+M1LzR70ODrMXdm/5swMXVbMJ6+NtE9cy4QQ9QzroTCR9mynJVCdj19dbAeh0E7TEDA4EeofiqTc2YEa1HJoM/LO578eM9j7HAMBDkskHu+JOnClD36ifrEYag4nZyOge2xKu3mj/KoA4F65Kv9ZapK1z+15XwCZMZ5ZtipFvl0RqPpkxjTltR6c4oDXGwTAdHD0PL2FybK42FzU/yNEHkGTegNSmFcqwd7nW0K9EcyHDXrvJ3NqISjJIq6O9KwbykcJzEF11XZAeimrpkov+2rU0yXDxagv5FzIioCR4p3BXDXtYhqlHtRSBALW1cyDl8k1QQGOk10zargpbI2xd88kC6xwLr7gKfkM3QRj9cm7l5g02ZrqCT2cnOPph9oLNQnabAf5h6gbkj+4BeUiYsapTfefPkbJpFtZLotk0ZH827E2GRfqSO3L45sMDkg8ZemKG18yxM3d2nz2w7ZGGb2AFsJhq31+RI9344lCAaOJPzp7byZZqNBh4EBpID7g4B/0muZk27OMw+x5IeDJtDDXgfJy6Xjststs7rvYSfVcb3o2xzdesJVTSjshjN5uBt8uhRGFAPzVbZA7CZKSdbBRoKV5/lcDRUBPvbFFmDQrNd0M3thL9DWDpZIM6Blx3FqsKbVTIjAVOix+A7oY1yvHYBUYN/ldalE9xYKufxraVZUpt3MxtqPbgCPhVqPEURxST25jvMHXVr3IgPLQfk5RsC040fOQxGAiEQQSeEMKpXCxqrXY2jy4rRyBtaRQLMn9KFM7Bo5kfZKpmXQ4H+yCi131UtxfxqyvBkBPtfzmokBCNPPahxctFukEE2PmE9MQwrlXg7zmXfSSEVihPzUD96aocFdwhqCbV+aOYYt8sZi5U3Ks+SjrZLcBfAkg+pYdgyRJITsSKYYbGO9gkvxUfWDT02+tLb2PyVo6VaomKZUgQgTgDxzEAkeEbb9FRsW4e7xBKHjsYYEh4C6AiUlvQBe/iXq7lqMwqJmZZ0/ucdc5tAQDjZvE0m6QrCms5yjQYaBAeCA+4N/gEWOEh/D9zIOMV2GTgiLlW//nKqt4qPYcXlzttd5gFEXYJBJiL1TNvyaUykpX2d3oqLF0vAdGn5UbNZ6v7HyAznkroIduMqN45Hzlat7XodoAu4AKM4baCuSaAhgAhtZu+mv68M8d/FaMi4tYQGQMjNDkcn3aquaXALJMwu/1v7S69YxEsoSyY/670xT+4rOmQojwAHusX/3VduP5sxNEeD7Qpk/Om7R6sEz3dzInpcJqM5DrtXf6oH/jaXuzSfNgvvq1DRrQNabYuWT/WLrn4OfWhh76tDz4nDiuuTnjgWul0r6QpiOkGLP2xlUGgO94qkiod3m+wRWFtaGgXrBUSx55LxvlrvX6N9UvwIOk7RygvPPj409nwHl7avcZBTib/HrHiFnaOVnPkStdQddxpY/o4Xj79iSUjGshvXH+cWlPebexR5k+EBvVG26z7Nwbq/xzKdXRQ+9aSPDZgOEyoyzv2+PZ3c/eXSmGmdWGAQWHt+A8jaQ6zcWaWX4WnyjQYeBAhyA+4OAfyrv1twvvbSjNCqJ08V4WW421i4xfL+a06rRq33WZeOZVxznc7+VoZFW0z17skjZVMZ6u50UsypSJUUTnUfnBegMU98iHOblK78h+CbKbrUCBA3BAKU5Ca74ltzSDxGULX74bdPty7uUlk00H3xNlML0DnV4GPRY6wHR4Eg14MvW5wC08PUYSwwvKqwzaU8OzVsPyrs/R5B5ruITEUjw81xVL37iX/uki4l/CXlA8s/fMRkBDOqlXijHue86DjBEFUhSZAlfHkEk1HTiF1kmGK9U6TOdLOyJik3Oo4OwDADFa4nXxyIBBs1h1hboNFhs15g9F7mcWYft2OeTBqpbPehQgbJ6tpasp7+gSubjA896hQsCw5piJaOqx+9GVuJI3BeJNyf+uqBixptN2nL5xBaA1ul2ZfIP4n+iA2wfq4BpAjbzaeaOxIEMRAhMocrDYVSavTZFkIX26kiY2k6XW1TYCM739wPv+ijHUz4PHL5TWaU0hb22Iz8RnGi+/IMpo0GGgQJYgPuDf4DnMRbQPUSWZW9tSX8xVPz6D+5wmtzRaHxUet/FAZzRFMFdhpilPytvJ2KfMZXM6ndzMTlTaPfBvXWEMzwpHG7phFtPR43wr1E51FcgzYapZsvYCNuia5pZUDu+XBAi6hurcRfJvsz/zQoFflTwny30J2/rs5GiBu8KoWs/QRsi55EYkMpwKG5hja9PpKarbYuiG1nBcZ/h+H/OwNmcioEqgP6Y8YlIS9fyntkRbTKhfAfJnQfMoDL87BrHCONhUwzfmAbkuZT5qx3SWLGjng4bU7Z43xCMaQgYc+QX2nQ3zEJSWNYb+fNK9o1scb1xZNgqiHRISv8X23T10cNusx/ng2gv0+agzsS9jtOT/n7V9mUZFnnYqWmJrsMjpim3CDQcwMd42U8nIizsIFxMb/EudplPEk4ZHr4ZMYPU7ClLOL2QKk2L7utXOMQzGLXT3g6ye02YDzGrEdTrOyVNK5bIiXE5wFgYR9PjmC0qHm1/Lk/zRirxMXEZN00TktMeo0GHgQKTgPuDgH/ngNJREddofCocDmuQ+N1N2egUGi15pW/IPdwevzqzdf8sM4eDuJfPrmuqBW7Bc6lKGV+rIBNzv2WnUkm7miuXRP4KqJTBsgHHkKiwZFNgjY+npFcd2vxgC26oxFJHnp0QvRswsyV3izCOnrDPycVV5SZjINo1ynJrBI0QdSOTIehGYCpRQvh0gYyqy5NQNNKnAb0R51wYsSU6s3zBqGRGDgu88SNkNnoTXJ223nSDLI2J1lot/sUPk1X7tY1hhIPDT3MnUY6d35HR6+64uCADYFJdr1C2awKVXaeNdKLZ6RCThZm3TbvS8DzTI0gDg/INs7hwN1AEmoAPazCXSx3ngMrED5LIWQMQ7imIzlorX+OsEpeldT3z/SMIrizchiCCoU1M1+W71FL+1WIzS5jxnIihWtL8kEslDbU9amQQLGxKt14Y+/AjzQyh2oDeM7TikoILMMR8I2w8ayATO7TuGbYYlSjDJ+fyHush6zGX9MSxiescsBJhrfTW2Kq7GaNBhoEC0ID7g3+A6FHUSTb84ckGSyGiL9rmgZAfeGUclOoQw6RZqYG+E3VVgw1oQuXmyDPdyBGQ8H0ENGuDadu+QFKaKIaspLCTGiBZuHXfuucReovDbEyXISlJFwYrcLc7M+vyMBOYFHclFdhoHGT0TvstBFh/ikOzvJMgPwQbrVgqdsouJPmSHuhGTk3TenT0ph/SDirmuDdVW5Dx9aDSkBLg+Cebr7zGYfKyILlARr2/tpLRZB8EuYi/94s+kU8td/ixTD7ctXh3syDveaPtwtP4JxpvKmfplrh+CklxQQrmSnLp9AsraS0ElGoGtcdZsbrk4OmQu46Z9cAOzRTMkd9GpoXpxwoW55FjBtW2xbY0NG6YJihdGZKD4pwDo4gKYlGvvnSD9qewIxilUDX9vOeCafjiJqKPYNxtjRXIDUidksUtx8khDIO72is0xwtdQ8zXgXAjkHYitu8VYz/0FovTtZZD/n7kg9zz458Tqixj32VtVOocVQMkUtfR70O8dvJlQfajEaNBh4EDDID7g4B/55QCMonLWYVhd6zlzyU4RykshQhfNTspM6yb6JBMiMByf/nYoZIsknLW68PSqEv0tnW4QpgrL1WuHSm0z9IzVYrBmLqTS+w9RHB9c1vi8gNE54u/8xrAq3rvU+HrKXz1jIkmFwUMW+jAyKqOwm1xjMi3LesAudGYlv6hfV2NqQ7ngQh8ItU3/+02b3gAYGKwLXEKosUizj8q8EPHcYTkdN9dVyz0qL/TkT9X5/keYg1RLnLfz693mJs8OhmkN8O4Juqt73vWXBEqKKTiAi4hm31rRyyPv7MXRGGCc3EpVyVTgqDghRmrqJ9QUuZLoHAPjivcIac1rJsfQ3ehzjEO6FLGSJHmXHXR5/vShuKOYlMflbDLAQvrOAE317D08IvsTzB7nYG57xxMXDCSRNMqCPk9yjWwK1eKUilJyvhnZgGAbFNUq+01srxKF83mqYiYJHYemwLEpB76brXhluI4NzbzkSVO1TdTF1OyEXeKOK7c9n0lCpdYLXOKwIY/gQajQYaBA0eA+4N/gOeT3H8vWNXxpEDAQtPIW4JiP3XuZD79scodGR/yxZ2ACAq9tqQI9F2E++Z6FEEFJ0pZCP+Ei9kTb6Ekzla92o14VLDTBHohI1CabSqmEN1jz9iThkM8EyMQFqBshvsshz4sxn2zBLjRLMr+qobIjLgVJOEsJZZZ6UpDMPpdKQZNAaXkVeuECGz5bSC8+BdAPkc7V/5fJqnnA0s8CC7XmG6brmtBtyJFAel2k2aNVbC8RImpWjlTzaTamYgyezn8VtYCXYkjCgmzkiPCbvCdssbbyYY4WPa5N0faVoYbgT026Ru5ljBRk18UJ0xdNG+in0ecxunbOgoQAjLtwgVhm00bpnrMKnA+G/atjXoJ8k23eTLQoM+STr/Yc9oYda/NkKvDZpgrq14kB3mtTFaUKR7OeF1tHRxneTc3+LGDbAeTFqNCz4vd0fBBNin9f+EDd2mFyU7hAHPKfAAIYy/JubebITLoNDBIjqv0f/4Jd0z8NpEo5LnZNZXnN4/BwdyjQYeBA4OA+4OAf0WREzJcSdqKdADzUdZxI4la0DymDkGsB+cWOuU8KfQoEVsG8+11TDZU5Pnf0ok7CNFFDickklWMppBHjePlcA8cR+mIxwXGd7fdban8uc5L4oR03Z89KfgpSH6gbU4buSJuCpPgHWTN7zwjzSB/XL5yxSUZnFbATXOX0olFh3xsRZRNxTKXmRu0kffgnSGkPL+O8/LplvNws9Ya9d6x6RdPLRFMgVoH1iEdf/mZ7szpbxHGn9S2pOxmm7m5qfv3Zm5XIHOISZ0ld2uMeEegTHhJliDlOPFQP+p+vlIFXeCc9LYKngvgNBmu62JvqjQIIOyoKOlUd2Rq8gPF5xN9O0bBH0xP1UVPVoyS2IrO+AZQEb3vFx4OKa7sD0be/MUPPYser/rzL282iZGbbz5mbyo03c/W7MWZqFwmcEt9w/OT+zWwhgrtPRQuOoF1Cu3s8kbkyQCwHWuc3yAiXT5ujeewDkl/5z50zWB5HIJ1aTbaUXzyg0NdjanqGaDCMnG+o0GEgQO/gPuDf4AzaJQikesFysRtjoAgkHX1WCgTi8UlgPugLrg0/sfSL9M3JPkXx23iEr4F8720xyWeG9sp1ijMCRV+y+S+EkawbfNbl52guFPEp+yrjzyJzHiCNMScGJEcm4+yjb7JKx5eeL2qTI2BZAh49uay64O7QKRrDza6lc99fFVNCl1+/d4qtTofZM3uVMgeRuwS2vdNSaK2lKah/++VfXgz/fawPNiz8a+vInwlz3MGbGEvfH3pcSZwgcPZbzArA/s22zNrcNd1LYRb9XRCfd9G1CaDXaAWnXKGTxwSc8K76vs4XDk6cMZhDxp/omBrD2wLnFWYjJ1MnZWbgLz+LkQIBN9FihC2KVwz5ceWCN79jL9uDug429nJlrLWyEUQ+NaE/obdovRZlJvxIfsxGJji0x3g9YtN6TNbJ7UuqkgpGRXb2KE/xsS1q6iRwRg3KxmyMLi6sLI58oz9sC7u4ch+y0LLGtJ6omSUWMQcNrfQrqy3Axr9ySfO062hUSWsV6NBcoED+4D7g3t4TNCQCL+ftRmg0iNFytwKqufNqd3er/Qu2HBXPObMDMj8b1+9OhTFaox718qgqQ9ipEIji227GyArAZtgeCQzkqxrAmCI260NB6HbI8qGKa9ZbEU1mefs70wltl92oeYVjmqvbtohkTced6/hK4TAtoyaT9yv2ZhdRMzjOcWl9PuEG5rT23EM1c2rkmoTYNw9HllOa1ryFFwP1i3M+LNdvZnxtCtZctaUXKsfQiHcFdHxM82MSn000kQYvm+UYSF44xZZ/G+0Pl6HGv4svtDgCS1+6ANbLRYo/sjmVVy8MrZ/96ShqG5x7dQDTQD2QSPLRG+kRaYkrJ+Rmd6JWkKZkJsVbzf1hsLurJEaGInWNbSYYdn9wj3sHzRLP8BN5erv585YG1f6K7DCiB5O450gu743sRwFfruW7oYPYB/ycht2YYyd8VaPtcMWcAeevb1FIdZ9W+95UckUI4p4jTjcH8IGxmpUAvyFqGmjQUuBBDeA+4NxbUt3gCp/lMUfNJbNhC85rcBMLNFMGQgD2tb418tXOHvbIU/VDki+k+eLAopDkwhSZZdjxroDG3j7C+yvemwv9Dppup/nklGoKZZRzZupGnL+JpEbeJb/OWNtu6f/cGINpBvXfoYe/kezCTm+QkPnzSGbMNxogAdp7cJX7m6HJh981HfcY8MTCUVoDP7QKoeevnQV9zjgjRbxUhv2tzscbtU/zPIaINUqS7Tj9vPyYt/33sxXwEtYe+6jheHlGbKowXpfaaLGHNq6mHGd61SEjRWBDkbBpcYoiDS2UBdSngthFb2WTXEbMYTHR/8tJ9tgzyCusgqLmlNjzz++B+yq+KYPLQ4GXTqBsf4DzLv9xCCfVza65oAbS1Kw+4I6Tz8xHtukdiiU3pV9q4I/CVw6ZV6pyjFw3hn7YJ8HNJileqrmLG3uo0FZgQR0gPuDYHItEz2LKWJ6b2mP0LyEzHuk63eWl1J5nVsalJi6E03lVGgEMd3gNwUvH1KEagMWR/V075QEd3CBZuJfY9kmAFp5X34WHbWE1wJuf1geeORZlt5jeXApSFH1Mz0BCk3y4Ewfvcwz3dvH/BRirVVmQxDfCoPxCYdNoM2ncZowL7s9IcMvXaaJ5KzfgxsEG4bR+aIPEdXJ82dep2QM+5ppqyRVIIdx1uWehFdqlmpsWmrQif3Q7y89ax6+2D7MYXw8mAWEI2J7qtGIKlN1BvoY9TKzSSUIMVJZOtoVXBqCc4zLQK4jvV+2agSHEJLHMuMZYZR4YnmgW5tfM9nP9CulBE1aQ4GcBQfLE7BifeVGy5656Pnw/lZf5ATRYYtGvefXZAn69RFBnKXKVolwKovWFI1G7aE1+T+zQg6dJd2n5tzC0so/vi07fp9HVdkzRfXg58g4o0GDgQSwgPsDZ2i4cziKvwNf6OUerzS3D4hmN1vbdcpDzEe0+i08cJn1ZcEtRhd4RPuWD3KXsyfxj1mYTmtoajQwmY9hEMJKjQUji/Q6/lo2wtmzPQKIqVRYayAkQnXCfbFxDRS4bF/+JwCBJl9zgOtuEGwgYtGrdprM8uHi8HXfS4jVbEusvkKqWN7ElYztMGiLexWMftC/+A0HBgTsvFutvpJKTIuntt1yT/3agB1+PHoCgYV4E5TNZIM4nxBDpPoTHtRPzJM1ZMzJw/wxJIKdjqLgEe4QRfTMBgWU6bqrqKtB9PXRof8JEMwS6Snpcnl+DejEJpsIam99qdm+B2sn73WPqdQbDtcAG0tV/CWXDJK4Sc9Jzta0Ix3Wg1ifPb8UWtIi+w6qYhs67nO/7AU9MuCllMEfaVjqjyOGZyADffrGQ3MbeCEKD9CtNINB9jn9c9EZPA5WXeZ3QHFUf15fdkKVaRBmxwg0NgVO3EYyDe3raV4WgsDnls6FgsIA4KOhVPqMo0GMgQTsgPuDf62KyE5tdCCubZ0nRkndt5TT1awDuGZo/EVuf5kX7K0hN3KwEqbA04UL3C/Xe7Wz/wcCRavbaFTUQq4y3xHbPRDC35dAg+hrpFGRvoSFVCwYMFhfAiCHnx6WI3FLbB41DEPIGS0ByuYU/cmRq8Te5pqS8C6F/n2ffYSRQgkL4GNAinBzZ6mnhEByGh9WkwZjeiADYiImuiDkI36dNt5srASD0bitsG9Pg+8loykhetgO894O2vTm4Y/1nKyWws2R71gAXnRaoKwI1ZNAy1wPZidqU7f4FrDkXNKJWiZECowEKe28A4Ba3Z6R/HJ8JQRIWRxvKQUnBLgOfi1kcnTmZ/wS+IoVzYPtMR2PHHpeRJYJU5z65uFJ3+o0C5dTRr/odGbYCvrOPoxGCNDFAEBEVqKeIvTQUY9J3Vw3ofCcvYbplKwD5m95LO8Bv8tqnAXoWKLWmyMvNdjrNW0l3VjSziroYLsuEhBhZz8fQcmrbtHtqbcSN95MQn8D1yiqnGJnNKxJwv6fo0F/gQUogPuDeX9Qp+Mcj8RSyTqibDnZUVNKnHQqLzTj2rVObwh9KTJv00NXag8pM6QizNzLTT+AIkehELlMhyRQmf8CqaX7A0Jgru0XD6DDiv9RYhWHnvaPTjJbydVz49qrkWuQRBrawEJ9CgmfA9RckVQ0UKPG03f3CReXP+StZNc2QTiKTTl7RWBfP7cgdw9vCAZ/2IB+9FRI5geJBGZ7r4e9yabkkZN/kwBXFiPKshMaWVqcIt0iqAQzGrB1aKlZRXcvRB3QYRaj1juIUW5PrKKp909vhEmTJqi6C+nd3gwDRSqj53Lwm/JCx2ujpWHg4GSzhzr0J25JFoe8wqNt4VPpOLoSwQydCZ7bRZQzJefdTMId9KZjnsBBNRvHs/YITU0fsMUspqwMZxey8PDloGhaGG9fLy4OFKlplA0QOyj/ES6S3ucfCigRULMVRQrm73GMS6DyvlSNbBlO0JBUijyuhmsAlwruLC/JUi/qfycz9vP6UXwjJA1idbQdhDyjQYOBBWSA+wObAtiCRYKkv35+bpr24xC7r99YsVj6s2j30vxq1D3kXAbvJr+sfWNWSpom4cF7x3905QEYsYj1oydJRs3Nd2wL8aI4NPeKYLrJNSqSXhtGG5XxmYWJwpDiXdQaX5fFIz65nxFAzxRxMg7KezqypulXxSiLdSulY2x1w5gTTLxVWztQviIYknGsoJhq47BN3V0XMSsksLJjipxT7TCqsNH0JazomASa4GZMbwA8cPN+fvlBb+1qmcbntdkqxsvHXi2lhKjRpl8XzyjQn+K5DiJS+p9P8IEz6QoqPo6WELX76WPY9IXyJNgZ9kO7pFBncr7LBrQr4o1DnUVQlnFp/Flm0GWLH7GYCFw2Bbm6uiQsCp7sY7cVloFkmmgtN+4jtv75bdgDafsTZI90drCFYAVTHBKKfRjxi01E7EM15Hy/irSvXFxeV4gbMQ/2u9kA2GI/29WIzqQW+TOLgaA7lENLrVVQtUxf5Vlmv08oCL86A3u/9E59JYe5dZ7sthg=");
```

```
private void playChannelAudio(String base64FormattedString) {
    String strippedAudioData = base64FormattedString.substring(base64FormattedString.indexOf(',') + 1);

    byte[] data = Base64.decode(strippedAudioData, Base64.DEFAULT);

    AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(
            AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 44100,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
            data.length,
            AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC);

    audioTrack.write(data, 0, data.length);
    audioTrack.play();
    audioTrack.release();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your audio data is encoded with Opus codec with a sample rate of 48000 Hz (detected by FFmpeg). You have given wrong sample rate as a parameter to the AudioTrack constructor (given 44100 but it's 48000) and also it's encoded with a codec, and AudioTrack expects raw/decoded PCM audio so it could be the reason for the white noise you are hearing. In order to play the audio correctly, first convert it to raw PCM audio data then encode it with Base64.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you point me towards something that would help me convert the audioData bytes[] array to raw PCM in JavaScript?

Comment: @HomerPlata Unfortunately, I don't know if there is any decoder in JavaScript for this job since I have never interested in these things, but doing quick research lead me to this GitHub repository (it uses node.js I think), I hope it helps: https://github.com/samirkumardas/opus-to-pcm

Comment: My next approach is trying to save the encoded data to my Android device as a temp file, and play it back with MediaPlayer (the uncompressed data is too large to send). I've tried to just write the bytes into an .ogg file, and provide that as the source but I'm getting java.io.IOException: setDataSourceFD failed.

Comment: @HomerPlata There should be a status number that describes the problem (you need to register a `OnErrorListener` via `setOnErrorListener`), but I think the problem is you are still providing the wrong format to the player. If you directly recording the audio from the previous recorder you've used in your question, it outputs MKV/WebM stream file and not an OGG file so the player cannot understand the file, or maybe `MediaPlayer` doesn't support those formats. It is beyond my knowledge.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have awarded the bounty because your answer steered me in the right direction. Armed with the knowledge of the particular codec I was using etc. I decided a better route would be to use a more generally accepted format (MP3) and have achieved my goal through that.